# Brake Specific Fuel Consumption of 2-stroke vs 4-stroke

Tags: engine, engine-theory, fuel-consumption, two-stroke, four-stroke

How much fuel do various types of engines burn per power output? I'm especially interested in naturally aspirated piston engines, and comparing two-stroke to four-stroke.

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brake_specific_fuel_consumption) gives the value for several specific engines, but they're mostly for either aircraft or marine applications.

Comment: Sorry. New to the site. Didn't post this under my account.

Comment: Hi Jeff, to merge your accounts you can follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge), if that doesn't help then flag the post for moderator attention, and give them the email address of the other account, and let them know it needs merging.

Comment: I don't know if engine manufacturers openly publish those specifications. I am sure they have them in a document somewhere but I doubt they are easy to find. Good luck finding them though.

Comment: Mayhaps, if none of better, better fit would be on Physics.SE?

Answer (score 6):

### *BSFC is just engineer-speak for how much fuel is consumed by the engine per unit of energy output*¹.

[This webpage](http://www.dynomitedynamometer.com/dyno-tech-talk/using_bsfc.htm) provides a very concise comparison for several different engines:

```
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------+
|                  Engine                  | @ 1K RPM | @ Peak Torque  | @ Peak HP |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------+
| 4-stroke (low compression, carburetor)   | 0.62     | 0.47           | 0.52      |
| 4-stroke (high compression, carburetor)  | 0.60     | 0.42           | 0.47      |
| 4-stroke (high compression, closed loop) | 0.52     | 0.35           | 0.42      |
| 4-stroke (supercharged, carburetor)      | 0.75     | 0.50           | 0.55      |
| 4-stroke (turbocharged, closed loop)     | 0.57     | 0.45           | 0.50      |
| 2-stroke (low compression, carburetor)   | 0.85     | 0.55           | 0.60      |
| 2-stroke (high compression, carburetor)  | 0.80     | 0.50           | 0.55      |
| Diesel 4-stroke                          | 0.35     | 0.25           | 0.30      |
| Diesel 2-stroke                          | 0.40     | 0.29           | 0.34      |
+------------------------------------------+----------+----------------+-----------+
```

---

### Observations

- ***4-strokes are more BSFC-efficient than 2-strokes***
- ***best BSFC occurs at peak torque***

  Because that's where the engine is most efficient
- ***less diesel needed per unit work compared to gasoline***

  Now you know why diesels are the [go-to choice for heavy trucks](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/23865/675).

---

¹ - Alternatively, BSFC = fuel flow rate per unit power

Comment: Now that's an answer!

Comment: Hmmm, I have trouble to understand your 'main reason'. One power stroke per rev should be more efficient than one per two revs, because every rev steals some power due friction. So, each power stroke of a 4S-engine  has to compensate twice the loss of a 2S-engine...

Comment: 2strokes dump a lot of unburned fuel into the exhaust due to the nature of their operation which, I believe, would be a detriment to their efficiency.

Comment: @DucatiKiller: It's clear that 2S are less fuel efficient for many reasons. The point is I don't see why one combustion per one rev is less efficient that per two. (Of course, the other reasons are implications of this)

Comment: @sweber I could be wrong. My reasoning is that the power needed to rotate the crank is small compared to the motive power generated by combustion, and the fuel is spent in only 25% of the 4S cycle compared to 50% of the time for 2S motors. Maybe ask that as a new question and see what others say?

Comment: @sweber I [posted up a question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/25049/675). Looks like you're right.