# Has anybody converted a bus from diesel drive to electric drive (hybrid) converting the old engine into a generator?

Tags: diesel, hybrid, electric-vehicle

I am aware that the vehicle will increase weight and that older engines must be modified to operate with less harmful impact to the ambient. I rather wonder about the accompanying effects and conditions, like need for noise insulation, operation of supporting units, etc.

Comment: Did you search before posting? This is relevant : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/23865/10976

Comment: @ Solar Mike: Yes I searched and found conversion from cars with fuel engines to electrical engines replacing each other. But my idea is to keep the existing engine (at its place, if possible), disconnect it from the drive shaft and convert it into a generator. AND connect the drive shaft instead to an electrical engine.

Comment: Sounds expensive....

Comment: Packaging is going to be a problem. If you leave the ICE in place, where do you put the electric motor, or generator unit? Where do you put the batteries. And if drive power is 100% electric, can you use a smaller ICE for power generation and run it at its most efficient rpm?

Comment: Diesel-electric drive is very common for train locomotives but not for road vehicles. The setup is usually very heavy, takes up a lot of space is does not necessarily offer better efficiency for the conditions that most road vehicles are operated in.

Comment: @Moab: Yes, however there is an engine available and already installed. I don't think it's cheaper to sell it at a junk price and buy a new generator instead.

Comment: @Chris Paveglio: That is one of my preoccupations. Well, my intention is to convert a bus into a motor home, so there is space available in general. But around the engine usually it isn't. That is one of the reasons why I am also thinking about taking a smaller ICE, since the full power provided by the existing engines is seldom if ever needed.

Comment: @MadMarky: You are right. However the power requirements are different between buses and locomotives. Locomotives must slowly accelerate a train and then keep an almost continuous speed for a while. Buses must be able to operate at long distance, in mountains and in cities with "stop and go". In addition they must accelerate much faster than locomotives to be able to flow with the traffic. ... Will say that consumption of power in locomotives is much more continuous than in buses. Engines in buses are "over-dimensioned" and only in very few moments operate at maximum of efficiency.